# Replace NOT IN with LEFT JOIN to obtain the same result

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a doubt about the second query in PL/SQL. I've this query:

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT c_id FROM tableB WHERE tableB.c_id = tableA.id)
```

Is it possible or correct change for something like this?:

```
DELETE FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.c_id
WHERE id IS NULL
```

But this show an error: `syntax error near at or near "LEFT"`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can't do that.

Comment: can you tell why? @OldProgrammer

Comment: Why do you have a doubt about the first query? Explain which rows you want to delete.

Comment: Using proper SQL syntax, you need to alias the table and delete the alias .. I would still consider this improper (The nested SELECT is the proper method), but the **syntax** should not throw any errors.  `DELETE A FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.c_id WHERE A.id IS NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible or correct change for something like this?:
>
> ```sql
> DELETE FROM tableA 
> LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.c_id
> WHERE id IS NULL
> ```

No, it is not possible nor correct as Oracle does not support the non-standard `DELETE FROM ... JOIN` syntax.

You can use:

```sql
DELETE FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE b.c_id = a.id);
```

or:

```sql
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT c_id FROM tableB);
```

Answer (score 0):

MT0's answer is probably what you want. I only want to add that there is a third method that could be useful in more advanced situations:

```
MERGE INTO tableA
USING (SELECT tableA.rowid AS row_id
         FROM tableA
              LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.c_id
        WHERE tableB.c_id IS NULL) src
ON (src.row_id = tableA.rowid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tableA.othercol=null -- meaningless change
                  DELETE WHERE 1=1
```